# Blower door DIY test

Tags: thermodynamics, thermal-conduction, thermal-insulation, thermal-radiation

Since in my area there is no way to do a blower door test for a house, I was thinking to do a DIY [blower door](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blower_door) test. Here is my test scenario:

1. Preheat the house before testing to have 10 degree Celsius difference from the outside air.
2. Run as many smaller fans inside the building that would mix the air that entered trough the blower installed on a door (and make an even temperature everywhere).
3. Turn on a blower fan that is installed on a door and calibrate it to a 50 pascal difference from the outside pressure.
4. Run it for a short period of time (like 10 minutes)
5. Record temperature drop from the start to the end of the blower session (and use graph to extract ACH).
6. Capture with thermal camera leaks from the house envelope.
7. Fix envelope and redo test.

I am not expecting to get a ultra high precision of ACH with this test. Most of the envelope has low thermal capacity with exception of flooring. To ensure that I don't have to deal with capacitance, I've chosen only 10 degrees differential and 10 minutes run. I've chosen to evenly mix the outside air as much as possible during the test, sorta to get closer to homogeneous gas temperature. In case that internal fans create too much heat, I'd correct results for that too.

Now my questions:

1. Should I just ignore flooring heat capacitance, or maybe to follow flooring temperature drop as well and in case of a big drop to correct the result? It's a glued ceramic tiling with 8cm concrete underneath it. How much this capacitance can affect results in such a short period of time?
2. Do you suspect I may be having big flaws in my plan that might get me significantly incorrect results? If so what they are and what I may change to improve results?

Answer (score 0):

> in my area there is no way to do a blower door test

I assume you mean there is no one you can pay to do this.  These tests are not geography-dependent.

> Turn on a blower fan that is installed on a door and calibrate it to a 50 pascal difference from the outside pressure.

You've created a blower door, this is the hard part. It would be simpler to "calibrate" it by determining your cfm (or whatever your SI units are) using airflow measurement devices at whatever pressure differential it runs at instead of worrying about exactly 50 Pa.  Your calcs and assumptions on thermal changes would have more errors than a home-made airflow estimate.  Handheld flow measurement devices are readily available, the electronic units now available cost less than the mechanical ones we used to use.

Once you have a pressure differential, leak detection is the same as if you have a professionally-run rig installed.  I think generally you are putting a vacuum on the house, and look for leak by feel, smoke, or IR if the temperature is different outside.

[Here is an example someone building their own.](https://www.greenbuildingadvisor.com/question/looking-for-success-with-diy-blower-door-test)